# How to create groups checking elements by attribute value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to identify several groups of elements that have the same text. To check that I created the element data-code with the hash of the content for comparison.

I'm would like to group different groups of elements with the same content.
Example:

```
Name    |   Message<br>
Mike    |   This is the same message    GROUP 1 -> show button<br>
John    |   This is the same message    GROUP 1<br>
Millie  |   This is the same message    GROUP 1<br>
Steve   |   This is the same messages   GROUP 2 -> show button<br>
Michael |   This is the same message    GROUP 1<br>
Alfredo |   This is the same messages   GROUP 2<br>
Paul    |   Totally different message<br>
```

```js
var found = {};

  $('*[data-code]').each(function(i,el){

   var $this = $(this);
   var same = $this.attr("data-code");



   if(found[same]){    
    $this.css('color', 'yellow');             
      }else{
          found[same] = true;
      }
    
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="messages-list-table">
 <tr>
  <th class="message-name">Name</th>
  <th class="message-body">Message</th>
  </tr>  
  <tr id="1">
   <td class="message-name">Mike</td>
    <td class="message-body" data-code="5652c0bcc277bf4c039686d">This is the same message</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="2">
   <td class="message-name">John</td>
    <td class="message-body" data-code="5652c0bcc277bf4c039686d">This is the same message</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="3">
   <td class="message-name">Steve</td>
    <td class="message-body" data-code="725c1424b123dabc3">This is the same messages</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="5">
   <td class="message-name">Michael</td>
    <td class="message-body" data-code="5652c0bcc277bf4c039686d">This is the same message</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="6">
   <td class="message-name">Alfredo</td>
    <td class="message-body" data-code="725c1424b123dabc3">This is the same messages</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="8">
   <td class="message-name">Paul</td>
    <td class="message-body" data-code="8cbsh7364hd94d8">Totally different message</td>
  </tr>

  
</table>
```

My code:
http://jsfiddle.net/bfeujdLc/

Comment: I don't get your question, explain why group 2 has group1 message

Comment: @Wils sorry that looked tricky. Text "This is the same message" = GROUP 1, with text "messages" in plural is GROUP 2.

Comment: so you want to display it in groups with same data-code?

Comment: Correct @Wils. I need to identify which groups have the same content.

Comment: can you add the expected output? I am still very confused.

Comment: @Wils the example above is the expected output. Basically I want to set a color or group the ones with the same data-code. If multiple elements with the same value appear, we group/flag that.

Comment: can you please review my answer? Is that works for you or not? Please comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try to implement your code this way.

```js
// js to generate array for all data-code
  var codeList = [];
  $('*[data-code]').each(function(a, el){
   var code = $(el).data('code');
   codeList.push(code);
  });
  // Js to find only duplicate values from array of all data-code 
  var duplicateOnly = [];
  duplicateOnly = codeList.filter((b, c, bb) => bb.indexOf(b) === c && bb.lastIndexOf(b) !== c);
  // js to generate random color code list as per new array length
  var colorCodeList = [];
  for(var code in duplicateOnly){
   var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
   var color = '#';
   for (var d = 0; d < 6; d++)
    color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
   colorCodeList.push(color);
  }
  // js to apply color to all groups
  for ( var e = 0; e < duplicateOnly.length; e++ ){
   $('*[data-code]').each(function(a, el){
    var code = $(el).data('code');
    if (code == duplicateOnly[e])
     $(el).css({'color': colorCodeList[e]});
   });
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="messages-list-table">
  <tr>
    <th class="message-name">Name</th>
    <th class="message-body">Message</th>
  </tr>  
  <tr id="1">
    <td class="message-name">Mike</td>
    <td class="message-body" data-code="5652c0bcc277bf4c039686d">This is the same message</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="2">
    <td class="message-name">John</td>
    <td class="message-body" data-code="5652c0bcc277bf4c039686d">This is the same message</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="3">
    <td class="message-name">Steve</td>
    <td class="message-body" data-code="725c1424b123dabc3">This is the same messages</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="4">
    <td class="message-name">Michael</td>
    <td class="message-body" data-code="5652c0bcc277bf4c039686d">This is the same message</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="5">
    <td class="message-name">Alfredo</td>
    <td class="message-body" data-code="725c1424b123dabc3">This is the same messages</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="6">
    <td class="message-name">Paul</td>
    <td class="message-body" data-code="8cbsh7364hd94d8">Totally different message</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="7">
    <td class="message-name">Kuldip</td>
    <td class="message-body" data-code="dsdasdw4394839482384">Demo message but different from all</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

this code generate random color code every time.

I hope this will works fine for you.

**NOTE:** this code is work for every length of you data-code list, you do not have to make change in this code.

Thank You...

Comment: Thank you @KuldipKoradia, you understood very well.

Comment: to take only codes that repeat more than one, how would you do? (the ones that don't repeat don't apply color) @KuldipKoradia

Comment: @IgorO I have make change in my javascript code as per your last comment now this code change the color code for only data-codes which comes more then once.

Comment: hey @IgorO, did you get the solution of your problem with the help of this newly updated code?

Comment: Welcome @IgorO.

Answer (score 3):

You can maintain an array of objects with the code and related color property:

```js
var colorCode = [{code:'5652c0bcc277bf4c039686d', color: 'red'},{code:'725c1424b123dabc3', color: 'green'},{code:'8cbsh7364hd94d8', color: 'blue'}];
$('*[data-code]').each(function(i,el){
  var code = $(this).data("code");
  var color = colorCode.find(c => c.code == code).color;
  $(this).css('color', color);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="messages-list-table">
  <tr>
    <th class="message-name">Name</th>
    <th class="message-body">Message</th>
  </tr>  
  <tr id="1">
    <td class="message-name">Mike</td>
    <td class="message-body" data-code="5652c0bcc277bf4c039686d">This is the same message</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="2">
    <td class="message-name">John</td>
    <td class="message-body" data-code="5652c0bcc277bf4c039686d">This is the same message</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="3">
    <td class="message-name">Steve</td>
    <td class="message-body" data-code="725c1424b123dabc3">This is the same messages</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="5">
    <td class="message-name">Michael</td>
    <td class="message-body" data-code="5652c0bcc277bf4c039686d">This is the same message</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="6">
    <td class="message-name">Alfredo</td>
    <td class="message-body" data-code="725c1424b123dabc3">This is the same messages</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="8">
    <td class="message-name">Paul</td>
    <td class="message-body" data-code="8cbsh7364hd94d8">Totally different message</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: somehow on Firefox I'm getting the .find(...) is undefined error.

Comment: @IgorO, I have tested in Firefox 70.0.1 and didn't find such error:)

Answer (score 0):

Note: Based on the question, I believe you are creating the `data-code` attribute server-side. I would prefer a server side solution that adds a class or style to the HTML output rather than the data-code attribute and adding styles with javascript.

If you would rather stick with javascript, here is a solution that uses a `Set` to create a unique list of data-code values, loops through those codes and assigns a preset css color to the `tr` elements that contain a `td` with the matching data-code. You'll need to set enough items in the colors array to cover all the unique content, or replace the colors array with a random color function maybe?

```js
var $codes = $('td[data-code]'),
    codeSet = new Set($codes.map(function(){ return $(this).data('code'); })),
    colors = ['#ff0aaa', '#bbaa33', '#33cc33', '#9900ff', '#0000aa'];
    
codeSet.forEach(function(code){
  $codes.filter('td[data-code=' + code + ']').parent('tr[id]').css({color:colors.shift()});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="messages-list-table">
  <tr>
    <th class="message-name">Name</th>
    <th class="message-body">Message</th>
  </tr>  
  <tr id="1">
    <td class="message-name">Mike</td>
    <td class="message-body" data-code="5652c0bcc277bf4c039686d">This is the same message</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="2">
    <td class="message-name">John</td>
    <td class="message-body" data-code="5652c0bcc277bf4c039686d">This is the same message</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="3">
    <td class="message-name">Steve</td>
    <td class="message-body" data-code="725c1424b123dabc3">This is the same messages</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="5">
    <td class="message-name">Michael</td>
    <td class="message-body" data-code="5652c0bcc277bf4c039686d">This is the same message</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="6">
    <td class="message-name">Alfredo</td>
    <td class="message-body" data-code="725c1424b123dabc3">This is the same messages</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="8">
    <td class="message-name">Paul</td>
    <td class="message-body" data-code="8cbsh7364hd94d8">Totally different message</td>
  </tr>


</table>
```